# Multiple Set Peer for VPN Failover

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, ipsec, cisco-vpn

I will have two Cisco routers at Location A serving the same internal networks, and one router in location B.

Currently, I have one router in each location with a IPSec site-to-site tunnel connecting them.  It looks something like:

Location A:

```
crypto map crypto-map-1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description Tunnel to Location B
 set peer 12.12.12.12
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
 match address internal-ips
```

Location B:

```
crypto map crypto-map-1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description Tunnel to Location A
 set peer 11.11.11.11
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
 match address internal-ips
```

Can I achieve fail over by simply adding another set peer at location B?:

Location A (New secondary Router, configuration on previous router stays the same):

```
crypto map crypto-map-1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
     description Tunnel to Location B
     set peer 12.12.12.12
     set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
     match address internal-ips
```

Location B (Configuration Changed):

```
crypto map crypto-map-1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
     description Tunnel to Location A
     set peer 11.11.11.11
     ! 11.11.11.100 is the ip of the new second router at location A
     set peer 11.11.11.100
     set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
     match address internal-ips
```

Cisco Says:

> For crypto map entries created with
>   the crypto map map-name seq-num
>   ipsec-isakmp command, you can specify
>   multiple peers by repeating this
>   command. The peer that packets are
>   actually sent to is determined by the
>   last peer that the router heard from
>   (received either traffic or a
>   negotiation request from) for a given
>   data flow. If the attempt fails with
>   the first peer, Internet Key Exchange
>   (IKE) tries the next peer on the
>   crypto map list.

But I don't fully understand that in the context of a failover scenerio (One of the routers as Location A blowing up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the right way to do it. You can also set the `default` keyword after `set peer ...` if you prefer to use one of the two routers by default

Comment: Worked like a charm for me